# psql copy from csv automatically generating ids

Tags: postgresql, psql

Well consider a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

So the table has a unique 'id' column that auto generates default values using a sequence.

Now I wish to import data from a csv file, extending this table. However "obviously" the ids need to be unique, and thus I wish to let the database itself generate the ids, the csv file itself (coming from a complete different source) has hence an "empty column" for the ids:

```
,username
,username2
```

However if I then import this csv using psql:

```
\copy public."user" FROM '/home/paul/Downloads/test.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

The following error pops up:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty colum from the CSV file is interpreted as SQL NULL, and inserting that value overrides the `DEFAULT` and leads to the error.

You should omit the empty column from the file and use:

```
\copy public."user"(name) FROM '...' (FORMAT 'csv')
```

Then the default value will be used for `id`.